# FFmpeg error m4v to flv requested bitrate is too low

Tags: ffmpeg, flv

---

### FFMPEG OUTPUT

---

### COMMAND

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '/home/machine/public_html/video_1355531272.m4v' -s '640x480' -sameq -ab '64k' -ar '44100' -f 'flv' -pass '1' -passlogfile '/home/machine/public_html/tmp/1355531273-50cbc4090d696-multipass'  -y /home/machine/public_html/tmp/1355531273-50cbc4090d2a9.flv &> /home/machine/public_html/tmp/1355531273-50cbc4090da7c.info
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '/home/machine/public_html/video_1355531272.m4v' -s '640x480' -sameq -ab '64k' -ar '44100' -f 'flv' -pass '2' -passlogfile '/home/machine/public_html/tmp/1355531273-50cbc4090d696-multipass'  -y /home/machine/public_html/tmp/1355531273-50cbc4090d2a9.flv &> /home/machine/public_html/tmp/1355531273-50cbc4090da7c.info
eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 960x540, 3428 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 5994 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-12-14 22:50:55
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 111 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-12-14 22:50:55
[buffer @ 0xdd079d0] w:960 h:540 pixfmt:yuv420p
[scale @ 0xdd07da0] w:960 h:540 fmt:yuv420p -> w:640 h:480 fmt:yuv420p flags:0xa0000004
[flv @ 0xdd041c0] requested bitrate is too low
Output #0, flv, to '/home/machine/public_html/tmp/1355531273-50cbc4090d2a9.flv':
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: flv, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, pass 2, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-12-14 22:50:55
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: adpcm_swf, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-12-14 22:50:55
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
-------------------------------
RESULT
-------------------------------
Execute error. Output for file "/home/machine/public_html/video_1355531272.m4v" was found, but the file contained no data. Please check the available codecs compiled with FFmpeg can support this type of conversion. You can check the encode decode availability by inspecting the output array from PHPVideoToolkit::getFFmpegInfo().
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the -sameq option. It does not mean same quality.